# About placing other people's Youtube videos in my Flutter app using "youtube_player_flutter"

Tags: flutter, dart, youtube

I'm currently building an app in Flutter.

I'm using a package called "youtube_player_flutter" to put other people's Youtube videos in my app.

Does "placing videos in the app with youtube_player_flutter" mean "embedded videos" as Youtube calls them?

I'm talking about copyright-related issues.
Is it the same as embedding a video in a website?

Youtube allows embedding of other people's videos, so as long as the owner (uploader) of the video allows embedding, others can embed without permission.
(If the owner doesn't allow the embedding, others can't embed.)

Is it safe to assume that placing a Youtube video in an app (using youtube_player_flutter) is the same as embedding it in a website?

Well, of course, in that case, if the video owner deletes the video, the corresponding embedded video in my app will also become unwatchable.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You need the api for videos obviously. And youtube providing thier api to open developers to use. you just need an api key for that.
go and follow the api doc with legal procedure, there will be no copyright issues. [youtube api doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I have already released that app of mine at the moment and I am able to put the video in my app without doing the work you have shown.

I don't recall ever having done the work you've shown, is that required?

I believe we can play the video of the specified videoId in the app by following the sample on the "youtube_player_flutter" page on pub.dev. (without registering with YouTube Data API).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).